# How to await axios response before emitting response in vuejs

Tags: javascript, async-await, vuejs2

I have a small component in vuejs for file uploading (using axios). I am trying to emit the response from the file upload like this:

```
methods: {
  ...
  upload (){
    axios.put(URL).then(response => {

    console.log('response', response)
    this.$emit('uploaded', response)

    }).catch(error => {

    })
  }

}
```

But in this code, even though the `console.log()` response shows up fine, the emit shows `undefined`. I think the emit is getting called before the response is ready.

Is there anyway to use async/await to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> console.log response shows up fine but the emit shows undefined.

Not sure what you mean by that, because if the response is available inside of `console.log` it should also be available inside of `this.$emit`. (Unless `this.$emit` itself is giving you `undefined` in which case you have scoping issues, but that shouldn't be the case as you seem to be using arrow functions).

> I think the emit is getting called before the response is ready

It is inside of a callback so it should only get called once the request completes.

But if you want to try **async / await** then do this:

```
async upload() {
  try {
     let response = await axios.put(URL);
     console.log('response', response)
     this.$emit('uploaded', response)
  } catch(error) {
     // error
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is working. I'll try it a couple of time to make sure, but I don't understand why you need the try/catch?

Comment: try catch is similar to .then and .catch, it's there so you know if your operation succeeded or failed